# Nginx proxy_pass for /api/

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, proxypass

I am currently deploying a ReactJS app to a Nginx server. The backend the application is located in a private network. I am currently using `http://my-domain.com/` to access the frontend and from the frontend I access the backend using `http://my-domain.com/api/`. I am trying to configure Nginx to pass from `http://my-domain.com/api/` to `http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com/api/`.

This is the configuration that I am running from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/my-domain.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my-domain.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api/ {
            proxy_set_header Host my-backend-loadbalancer.com;
            proxy_pass http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

I get a Bad Request error with this approach. I would like to know if I am following good practices in terms of accessing a backend within a private network and how can I make this work.

***UPDATE***
I have tried this configuration, but it seems that is not passing the arguments. Because when I try `http://my-domain.com/api/` it redirects to `http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com` whit out any argument on it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/my-domain.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com;
    }
}
```

Here's what I found in `error.log`.

```
2022/11/04 15:57:52 [error] 4749#4749: *3 no resolver defined to resolve internal-backend-213123123.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com, client: 10.0.0.78, server: www.my-domain.com, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.com", referrer: "http://my-domain.com/"
```

Comment: The `$is_args$args` is causing the problem. Try: `proxy_pass http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com;` - Also, the `proxy_set_header Host my-backend-loadbalancer.com;` is unnecessary, as it is already specified in the `proxy_pass` statement.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Unfortunately, I tried this option but when I try `http://my-domain.com/api/`, it passes to `http://my-backend-loadbalancer.com` without the arguments. That's why I added that part, is there any other option that I could try?